# Issue with stopping Bluetooth scanning in Swift static library

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, static-libraries

I have built a static library in Swift that handles Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) operations like scanning, connection, and authentication. When I import this library into my project and use it to scan for devices for two seconds, if devices are found, I connect to the nearest device. However, after scanning for two seconds, when I try to stop scanning using the centralManager.stopScan() method, it returns nil.

Here's how I'm using the library in my view:

```
import MYStaticLib

@ObservedObject private var myBLEController = BluetoothViewController()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    myBLEController.stopScanning()
    if myBLEController.devicesFound.count > 0 {
        print("Devices Found : \(myBLEController.devicesFound.count)")
        print("Device With Minimum Distance : \(myBLEController.devicesDistance.min()!)")
        print("Device With Minimum Distance Index : \(myBLEController.returnLowestValueIndex())")
        myBLEController.device = myBLEController.devicesFound[myBLEController.devicesDistance.returnLowestValueIndex()]
        self.connect(dev: myBLEController.device!, uida: uida)
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the BluetoothViewController class within the library:

```
class BluetoothViewController: UIViewController, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var device: CBPeripheral?
    @Published var devicesFound : [CBPeripheral] = []
    var devicesDistance : Array<Int> = []

    func startScanning () {
        if isBluetoothOn {
            devicesFound = []
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [])
        }
    }

    func stopScanning (){
        centralManager.stopScan()
    }

    func connect(dev:CBPeripheral, uida : String){
        centralManager.connect(dev,options: nil)
    }

}

extension BluetoothViewController {
    // All Delegate methods
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {}
    // didDiscover
    // didConnect
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that if I create this controller within the app, it works fine. However, when I use it within the library, it throws an exception.

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, static-library, centralmanager, coredatadelegate

Comment: "it throws an exception." What excecption?

Comment: "centralManager is nil", when I call centralManager.stopScan() after delay of 2 seconds.

Comment: It depends then on the logic of the view having the `BluetoothViewController`, does it get released, then the VC gets released too?

Comment: View does not get released because I start scanning for peripherals and stop scanning for peripherals using the button.

Comment: Why have you combined these functions into a UIViewController? That seems like a poor design choice. Bluetooth code should be in its own object.  And why is your central manager an implicitly unwrapped optional?  Making it an optional will at least eliminate the crash. Your code doesn't seem to create a CBCentralManager